# Why does $\frac{1}{z}$ not have an antiderivative but $\frac{1}{z^2}$ does?

Tags: complex-analysis

On the complex plane $\mathbb C-\{0\}$, it is stated that $\frac{1}{z}$ does not have an antiderivative. But apparently $\frac{1}{z^2}$ does and I find this confusing because both functions have a pole at 0 so that means any closed curve around the origin is not 0 right?

Comment: One has non-vanishing path integrals around that hole, the other does not. That's all it takes, What's the problem? Antiderivatives are guaranteed to exist only for simply connected regions.

Comment: please use the correct terminology, if you are studying complex analysis it is not called a hole, it is a pole

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : is it a hole or a pole?

Comment: @jimjim I would say that it is a pole of both functions, $f(z)=1/z$ and $g(z)=1/z^2$. But it is a hole in the complex plane. For me a pole is associated to a (holomorphic) function.

Comment: i havent even heard of the word pole yet so far. actually the word is introduced in the following section after this one

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a function has a pole does not mean that its integral along a closed curved around the pole is not zero. This depends on the value of the residue of the function at this pole (the residue at $z=0$ of $f(z)=1/z$ is non-zero, but the residue of $f(z)=1/z^2$ is zero).

Comment: Though the residue theorem critically depends on already knowing that the integral of $1/z$ over the unit circle is $2\pi\mathrm i$ while the same integral vanishes for $1/z^n,~n>1$. The whole idea is to reduce the integral of an arbitrary function to integrals of $1/z^n,~n\in\mathbb N_+$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes of course. My answer is rather to get a way to "see" directly, in simple cases when you have the Laurent series of your function, if the integral vanishes or not. But , I agree that the calculus of the integral $1/z^n$ comes before all of that, and the most direct answer would be : "compute the integral and see why it is/it is not zero".

Comment: the word residue and pole are not introduced to me until the next few chapters. I guess I'll have a much better understanding after I've worked on those chapters.

Answer (score 1):

So first off, poles do not inherently mean that integrals around the pole vanish. The important relationship is that all closed integrals vanish if and only if there is an antiderivative, and if the domain is simply connected, then an antiderivative exists. So on simply connected domains, closed integrals vanish. But just because all closed integrals vanish, the domain doesn't have to be simply connected. It's just a one-way implication.

Now to the functions at hand: there are a few different ways to see why one has an antiderivative, while the other does not. For one, we already know that all functions of the form $z^n$ with $n\in\mathbb Z\backslash\{-1\}$ have an antiderivative given by $\frac{1}{n+1}z^{n+1}$. And we can already see from this formula that at $n=-1$ something special should happen, since this formula would force us to divide by $n+1=-1+1=0$, which we can't. So this formula cannot possibly apply. We have to think of something different. Interestingly, we can observe that an antiderivative of $z^{-1}$ must be a holomorphic logarithm, up to an additive constant. If $F$ were such an antiderivative, then the derivative of $F\circ\exp(z)$ would be $\exp(z)F'\circ\exp(z)=\frac{\exp(z)}{\exp(z)}=1$. So $F\circ\exp$ is an antiderivative of $1$, so $x+c$ for some $c\in\mathbb C$. So $F$ is a logarithm, up to the constant $c$. But we know that there is no holomorphic logarithm on the punctured complex plane, so that's impossible.

Or we could directly calculate the integrals for a nice contour, like the unit circle. Then we have
$$\int_{\vert z\vert=1}z^n\mathrm dz=\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm i\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}(\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})^n\mathrm dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(n+1)t}\mathrm dt.$$
Again, we see that for $n=-1$, something special happens. For all other $n$, the integrand is periodic in a way such that the integral will evaluate to $0$. But for $n=-1$, it is constant, so it won't evaluate to $0$. So the integral doesn't vanish for $n=-1$, but it does vanish for all other $n$.